# How to verify code changes done by specific Author in pipeline declarative script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have repo which contains multiple projects and whenever we do release our script changes all snapshot with specific versions.

which may result in triger to build jenkin job.

Currently i am using job and navigating through list of project and restricting by following shell script.

- How i can achieve same in declarative pipeline to build sub projects separatly and identify author of changes?
- If i run manually do declarative able to identify that code got change?

  for file in cat projects-list.txt; do if test -d $file; then

  ```
  echo "Checking project $file"
  AUTHOR=$(git log -1 --format='%an' -- "$file")
  if [ "${AUTHOR}" != "release" ]; then
    echo "Detected changes in project $file"
    cd $file
    echo "Building project $file"
    mvn clean install -U`
  ```

I also tried following script but variables are printing null, i am testing by "pipeline script" option of pipeline plugin.(inline script)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('checkout') {
            steps {
                git url: 'https://my.com/scm/java/my.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building.. branch'+env.BRANCH_NAME
                echo env.CHANGE_AUTHOR
                echo env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have introduce following script in steps, if someone has better solution please update

```
script {
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    def commitAuthor ="" 
    def commitMsg    =""
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            commitAuthor = "${entry.author}"
            commitMsg    = "${entry.msg}" 
            echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"        
        }
    }

    if(commitAuthor == 'release' || commitMsg.contains("INTERIM") ) {
        echo "condition meet"                                                                     
    }
}
```